# Can I disable the security confirmation for certain languages in org-mode src blocks?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've written my own little language for displaying trees - it's just some string-replacement for `tkiz-qtree`. Can I somehow disable the security questions for that language? I'm developing a habit to hit `y` 6 times when exporting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it's written in [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Code-evaluation-security.html#Code-evaluation-security) :

> User Option: org-confirm-babel-evaluate
>   When t (the default), the user
>   is asked before every code block evaluation. When nil, the user is not
>   asked. When set to a function, it is called with two arguments
>   (language and body of the code block) and should return t to ask and
>   nil not to ask.

So just set this variable to `nil` if you trust your source code blocks.

You can disable the message for your language:

```
(defun my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)
    (not (string= lang "tkiz")))  ; don't ask for tkiz
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
```